# Have to press IBAction twice for calculation?

Tags: ibaction

The app i'm making is a basic style student loan calculator. The bit i'm stuck at is the button calculation. The user has to enter in multiple values, they then click the calculate button and everything works out apart from the bottom calculation, for that to be worked out I have to press the calculate button again.

This image shows what the app looks like after the calculate button has been pressed once.

[Image link 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JuHH.png)

This image shows what the app looks like after the calculate button has been pressed twice. The bottom calculation is only then calculated

[Image link 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8Sd6.png)

Here's the current code i'm working with:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Repayment Calculator
//
//  Created by on 04/11/2015.
//  Copyright (c) 2015. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize button1, textbox1, textbox2, textbox3, startingsalary, repaymentlabel, debtlabel, startingrepayments, timetakentopayoffloan, realtimetakentopayoffloan, debtamounttextfield, annualrepaymentstextfield, monthlyrepaymentstextfield,weeklyrepaymentstextfield, payoffloantextfield, testlabel, annualrepaymentstest, totaldebtamounttest;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// - (IBAction)button1Press:(id)sender {
//    [button1 setTitle:textbox1.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// }

//The start of the calculate button that starts the calculations.

 -(IBAction)button1Press:(id)sender

{

    int x = ([textbox1.text intValue]);
    int y = ([textbox2.text intValue]);
    int q = ([textbox3.text intValue]);
    float startingsal = ([startingsalary.text intValue]);


    int debtamounttfield = ([debtamounttextfield.text intValue]);

    float annualrepayments = ([annualrepaymentstextfield.text floatValue]);

    //PROBLEM STARTS
    float p1 = debtamounttfield /annualrepayments;//([debtamounttextfield.text intValue]);

    if(isnan(p1) || isinf(p1)){
        p1 = 0.00;
    }


    [testlabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.01f",p1]];

    [totaldebtamounttest setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", debtamounttfield]];

    [annualrepaymentstest setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", annualrepaymentstextfield]];

    [payoffloantextfield setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.01f",  p1]];
    //PROBLEM ENDS


    [debtamounttextfield setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i" , (x + y) * q]];



    int arp = (startingsal - 16910)*0.09;

    [annualrepaymentstextfield setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",  arp ]];

    [monthlyrepaymentstextfield setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",  (startingsal - 16910)*0.09/12]];




    [weeklyrepaymentstextfield setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",  (startingsal - 16910)*0.09/12/4]];

    //Error Handling
    //Enter starting salary
    if ([startingsalary.text isEqualToString: @""]) {

        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                                 message:@"Please enter your expected starting salary"
                                                                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        //We add buttons to the alert controller by creating UIAlertActions:
        UIAlertAction *actionOk = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                                                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                         handler:nil]; //You can use a block here to handle a press on this button
        [alertController addAction:actionOk];
        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];


    }

    //If course length is equal to 0
    if ([textbox3.text isEqualToString: @"0"]) {

        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                                 message:@"Your course lenth cannot be 0 Years. Please enter a different value"
                                                                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        //We add buttons to the alert controller by creating UIAlertActions:
        UIAlertAction *actionOk = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                                                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                         handler:nil]; //You can use a block here to handle a press on this button
        [alertController addAction:actionOk];
        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }


    //If course length text field is empty
    if ([textbox3.text isEqualToString: @""]){
        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                                 message:@"Please enter your current course length"
                                                                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        //We add buttons to the alert controller by creating UIAlertActions:
        UIAlertAction *actionOk = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                                                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                         handler:nil]; //You can use a block here to handle a press on this button
        [alertController addAction:actionOk];
        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];


    }

    //Error handling for Annual University Fee
    if ([textbox1.text isEqualToString: @""]){
        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                                 message:@"Please enter your annual University Fee."
                                                                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        //We add buttons to the alert controller by creating UIAlertActions:
        UIAlertAction *actionOk = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                                                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                         handler:nil]; //You can use a block here to handle a press on this button
        [alertController addAction:actionOk];
        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];


    }

    if ([textbox2.text isEqualToString: @""]){
        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                                 message:@"Please enter your annual maintenance loan value."
                                                                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        //We add buttons to the alert controller by creating UIAlertActions:
        UIAlertAction *actionOk = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                                                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                         handler:nil]; //You can use a block here to handle a press on this button
        [alertController addAction:actionOk];
        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];


    }

}




-(IBAction)clearbutton:(id)sender {

    [textbox1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];

    [textbox2 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];

    [textbox3 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];


    [startingrepayments setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Loan at start of repayments: "]];

    [startingsalary setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];

    [realtimetakentopayoffloan setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];

    [debtamounttextfield setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];

    [annualrepaymentstextfield setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];

    [monthlyrepaymentstextfield setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];

    [weeklyrepaymentstextfield setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];

    [payoffloantextfield setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@""]];

    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Cleared"
                                                                             message:@"All fields have now been cleared."
                                                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    //We add buttons to the alert controller by creating UIAlertActions:
    UIAlertAction *actionOk = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                     handler:nil]; //You can use a block here to handle a press on this button
    [alertController addAction:actionOk];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}




@end
```

A huge thank you in advance for anyone that can help me on this one. It's something I've been stuck on for a while now and would love to get fixed.

Comment: what's your question? both the images you attached looks same

Comment: Sorry! Ill fix that now, one moment

Comment: I'm wondering if this to do with dismissing the keyboard.  Try `[self.view endEditing:YES];` as the first line in the `IBAction` method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I´m new on this and I've no much idea at all, but I´ll try to help you.
English isn´t also my native language so excuse my mistakes please, I´ll do my best.
So, it seems like your data gets stuck somewhere. The solution I'm gonna give you maybe helps you while it is fixed once for all.
I´ll put an NSTimer which calculates the values in a very short time interval when all the textfields are filled, so that makes the "first press" and gets the result. 
Then, the Calculate button only displays in a label or in a textfield (as u want) the result. Once is shown, you invalidate the NSTimer so that it does´t make an error.

I don´t know if You will understand me, please contact me for any question you have about this message.

The code I told you would be kind of this:

```
//make a values int: 
int valor;


//in your viewDidLoad probably:
NSTimer *intervalo = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/3.0) target:self selector:@selector(autocalculate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


-(void)autocalculate{
//the code that you have in your UIButton "Calculate" 
//take the result into the int valor so it can be use later
}

-(IBAction)show{ 
**thenameofyourtextresultstextfield**=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", valor];
[intervalo invalidate];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: There should be no reason to use a timer to work around this issue.  It's better to solve the issue than to work around it.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, but its for meanwhile